# Android Facebook integration with proguard

Tags: android, facebook

I made sure the key hash I send to Facebook is the same as defined in the app settings on Facebook.

I added the following to the proguard-project.txt file:

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature

and still I get the following error when my app starts:

*com.facebook.as: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract org.json.JSONObject com.facebook.c.c.c() at com.facebook.c.h.a(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.c.f.b(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.c.f.invoke(Unknown Source) at $Proxy0.c(Native Method) at com.facebook.b.bo.a(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.b.bo.onPostExecute(Unknown Source) at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632) at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by: com.facebook.as: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract org.json.JSONObject com.facebook.c.c.c() at com.facebook.c.h.a(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.c.f.b(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.c.f.invoke(Unknown Source) at $Proxy0.c(Native Method) at com.facebook.b.bn.a(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.widget.c.a(Unknown Source) at com.facebook.widget.c.doInBackground(Unknown Source) at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) ... 4 more*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you enabling progaurd?

Comment: Good question, apparently the problem was here: proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt while the actual name is proguard-project.txt. Now it works

Comment: haha hope that help. good luck.